# Jhipster v6.10.5, with reactJs, postgresql, oauth2/keycloack and protractor - generates failing date e2e-test

Tags: jhipster

I'm creating a monolith app and when importing the entity.jdl (using JDL-Studio) it creates an update-e2e-test that fails when comparing dates.
The test fails in:

```
await this.setCreateDateInput('01/01/2001' + protractor.Key.TAB + '02:30AM');
expect(await this.getCreateDateInput()).to.contain('2001-01-01T02:30');
```

with the exception:

```
AssertionError: expected '10120-01-26T02:30' to include '2001-01-01T02:30'
```

The date-utils.ts use: export const APP_LOCAL_DATETIME_FORMAT = 'YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm';

so why it return 10120-01-26T02:30'? Is this i known bug?
Manually I can create a new 'activity' and I can see that the date is correct (in h2disk).

---

Im using the following yo-rc-json and entity.jdl

yo-rc.json

```html
{
  "generator-jhipster": {
    "promptValues": {
      "packageName": "se.carestra.learn.jhipster"
    },
    "jhipsterVersion": "6.10.5",
    "applicationType": "monolith",
    "baseName": "activity",
    "packageName": "se.carestra.learn.jhipster",
    "packageFolder": "se/carestra/learn/jhipster",
    "serverPort": "8080",
    "authenticationType": "oauth2",
    "cacheProvider": "ehcache",
    "enableHibernateCache": true,
    "websocket": false,
    "databaseType": "sql",
    "devDatabaseType": "h2Disk",
    "prodDatabaseType": "postgresql",
    "searchEngine": false,
    "messageBroker": false,
    "serviceDiscoveryType": false,
    "buildTool": "maven",
    "enableSwaggerCodegen": false,
    "embeddableLaunchScript": false,
    "useSass": true,
    "clientPackageManager": "npm",
    "clientFramework": "react",
    "clientTheme": "darkly",
    "clientThemeVariant": "primary",
    "creationTimestamp": 1606418633256,
    "testFrameworks": ["protractor"],
    "jhiPrefix": "jhi",
    "entitySuffix": "",
    "dtoSuffix": "DTO",
    "otherModules": [],
    "enableTranslation": false,
    "blueprints": []
  }
}
```

entity.jdl

```html
entity Activity {
    title String required,
    startHour Integer required min(0) max(23),
      endHour Integer required min(0) max(23),
    activationDate Instant required,
    deactivationDate Instant,
    createDate Instant required,
    lastChangedDate Instant
}
```

And the failing test result:

```html
carestra:activity $ npm run e2e

> activity@0.0.1-SNAPSHOT e2e /Users/carestra/_A/repos/JHipster/activity
> protractor src/test/javascript/protractor.conf.js

[20:32:23] I/launcher - Running 1 instances of WebDriver
[20:32:23] I/direct - Using ChromeDriver directly...


  Account
    ✓ should fail to login with bad password
    ✓ should login with admin account

  Administration
    ✓ should load metrics
    ✓ should load health
    ✓ should load configuration
    ✓ should load audits
    ✓ should load logs

  Activity e2e test
    ✓ should load Activities
    1) should create and delete Activities


  8 passing (8s)
  1 failing

  1) Activity e2e test
       should create and delete Activities:
     AssertionError: expected '10120-01-26T02:30' to include '2001-01-01T02:30'
      at ActivityUpdatePage.<anonymous> (src/test/javascript/e2e/entities/activity/activity-update.page-object.ts:119:60)
      at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
      at fulfilled (node_modules/tslib/tslib.js:110:62)
      at runMicrotasks (<anonymous>)
      at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:93:5)
```

Comment: Looks like a bug to report on github rather than a question for stackoverflow

Comment: bug created, https://github.com/jhipster/generator-jhipster/issues/13147